# Rails tree model with tree-node attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I need to create a model, in Rails (5.2), for a tree structure with the following requirements:

- the tree leafs can be reused in multiple tree structures
- tree nodes can also have attributes (like quantity in the example
  below)

I decided to use the following database model:

[image: db model]

The migrations to create these tables look like this:

```
class CreateItems < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :items, id: false, primary_key: :item_no do |t|
      t.string :item_no, null: false
      t.string :item_name
      t.float :inventory

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :items, :item_no, :unique => true
    execute "ALTER TABLE items ADD PRIMARY KEY (item_no);"
  end
end

class CreateTrees < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :trees, id: false, primary_key: %i[parent_item_no child_item_no] do |t|
      t.string :parent_item_no
      t.string :child_item_no
      t.float :quantity

      t.timestamps
    end
    execute "ALTER TABLE trees ADD PRIMARY KEY (parent_item_no, child_item_no);"
  end
end
```

The problem I have is to setup the Rails models to reflect this data model using associations.

```
class Tree < ApplicationRecord
  self.primary_keys = :parent_item_no, :child_item_no
  belongs_to :item_no, class_name: 'Item', foreign_key: :parent_item_no
  has_many :item_no, class_name: 'Item', foreign_key: :child_item_no
end
```

The parent relation is ok, but the `has_many` is clearly not working as it expects the foreign key in the Item table.
I need a way to access the children of a tree node.

How would you do it?
I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: If I get it correctly, then you need a many-to-many association, since you want to reuse leafs in multiple trees. Thus, tree node can have many children nodes and belongs to many parent nodes. There is has_and_belongs_to_many in Rails, or you can create intermediate model/table manually.

Comment: @ololobus indeed, it is a many-to-many association, but I'm trying to model it without adding an intermediate table. I think the two tables I proposed fit the requirements, but I can't see a way to use Rails associations without adding a 3rd table.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would do something like:

```
class Tree < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent_item, class_name: 'Item', foreign_key: :parent_item_no
  belongs_to :child_item,  class_name: 'Item', foreign_key: :child_item_no
end
```

Then, you would need to do something like:

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :children_trees, class_name: 'Tree', foreign_key: :parent_item_no
  has_many :child_items, through: :children_trees
  has_many :parent_trees, class_name: 'Tree', foreign_key: :child_item_no
  has_many :parent_items, through: :parent_trees
end
```

You might need to futz with that a bit as it is untested.

Then, you will be able to do something like:

```
@item.child_items
@item.parent_items
```

Because you stipulated that an `Item` (what you call a "tree leaf" but could also be called a "node") can be reused in multiple tree structures, you'll need to do some fancy foot work to make sure that you're retrieving the parent and child items in the context of a particular tree. But, that's a different problem.

Personally, I'm not sure what this bit is about:

```
self.primary_keys = :parent_item_no, :child_item_no
```

If you want to ensure that there is only one `Tree` instance between two given `Item`s, then I would suggest that you [validate uniqueness using a scope](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness).

I don't know why you're using `_no` instead of `_id`. If you had `parent_item_id` and `child_item_id` instead of `parent_item_no` and `child_item_no`, then I think you could do:

```
class Tree < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent_item, class_name: 'Item'
  belongs_to :child_item,  class_name: 'Item'
end
```

But, perhaps you have a good reason for going against convention.

BTW, `Tree` seems like an odd name for the class. The `Tree` is the collection of all the edges and nodes in your hierarchical structure. But, you're using `Tree` to mean an edge in your structure. That seems peculiar to me. But, hey, it's a matter of personal preference. So, if it floats your boat, go for it!

Comment: The `Tree` primary key is indeed for making sure there is only one link between two `Item`s. Why would you prefer a validation?
... and yes, `Tree` is not the best name .. thanks!

Comment: I guess I prefer a validation because (1) IMO, it is more semantically representative of your intention, (2) it doesn't require a gem (maybe I'm wrong, but I guessed you're using the `composite_primary_keys` gem), (3) I speculate that it might have lower query overhead - but that's pure speculation on my part and I could be 100% wrong, (4) it's conventional and in Rails land, conventional == goodness (generally speaking).